# send data from unity to java android

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I created an unity project and I'm trying to send data from c# to unity. on my c# code I implemented this code :

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
jo.Call("shareText","test","test");
```

It works on android on  my activity :

```
public class UnityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void shareText(String AppId,String PublisherID) {
        Log.e("test","test");
        Log.e("test",AppId);
        Log.e("test",PublisherID);
    }
}
```

but in another case I created a custom view containing unityPlayer.

So now I have UnityActivity containing UnityView (which is a java class) and the last one contain my custom view (extend linearLayout) with unityPlayer and with the same code it didn't work :

```
public class CstUnityView extends LinearLayout {
    private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

    public void shareText(String AppId,String PublisherID) {
        Log.e("test","test");
        Log.e("test",AppId);
        Log.e("test",PublisherID);
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea why it didn't work ?!

Comment: Because it is not an activity?

Comment: yes it's not but I'm using that custom view into an activity. unity works fine but i didn't get the data from unity to android

Comment: Why do you want it inside a linearlayout? Instead call it to activity where you are using that linearlayout.

Comment: I'm using it as a custom view.

Comment: but where your log is from your currentActivity as you put on your second line AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

Comment: I update my question to explain more the structure of my case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149540/discussion-between-chogath-and-ray-hong).

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that the `shareText()` in your custom linearlayout cannot be called by unity unless it is declared in activity. It needs to be declared in your activity in order for your unity `Call` to ignite the function.

You can check the console log first to make sure it has been called. 
After, you can use those that you have received from your activity to your custom layout view.

in your activity

```
protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//this creates unityplayer with context to your activity
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);

//this requests focus so that the currentactivity is set to your activity
//that is why shareText() can be called from your Unity
mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();

//call layout here
yourLinearlayout customlayout = new yourLinearLayout();
//do what you want to do with this customlayout
//....
}
public void shareText(String AppId,String PublisherID) {
    Log.e("test","test");
    Log.e("test",AppId);
    Log.e("test",PublisherID);
}
```